# Round corners on a Bootstrap link

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a link and I want round corners on it.

I've tried with this code with no success, here are all samples I tried.

What I am thinking could be the mistake is that I'm using `btn btn-success` to change a link, but I cant find any CSS for a link in Bootstrap.

### My code

```css
.RoundIT{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            
 
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button1" value="normal Button" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1" class="btn-success RoundIT" style="width:25%">
 <p>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hypProsegui" class="btn btn-success RoundIT" href="Index.aspx" style="width:30%;min-width:130px">link with css roundIT</a>
 <p>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hypProsegui" class="btn btn-success" href="Index.aspx" style="width:30%;min-width:130px">link without css RoundIT</a>
 <p>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hypProsegui" class="btn-success RoundIt" href="Index.aspx" style="width:30%;min-width:130px">link without css btn and RoundIT</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt was quite good, but you had an issue typing the class: `class="btn-success RoundIt"` it should be `RoundIT`, classes are case sensitive in CSS.

I improved your CSS styling on `RoundIT` class to give it a better button feel. Added `text-decoration:none`to remove the underline of the link text, also some padding and removed some properties which where not necessary.

```css
.RoundIT{
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    transition: 400ms ease;
}
```

```html
<html style="padding:50px">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</script>

  <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hypProsegui" class="btn-success RoundIT" href="Index.aspx" style="width:30%;min-width:130px">link without css btn and RoundIT</a>

</html>
```